# How to read child of dotted session in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on project where some has writing content to session with dotted notation as shown in below Example, I want find out if Symfony is aware of dotted notation for sessions, so that all child of somedata.a  can be retuned as an array in a **controller**.

Example:

```
$this->get('session')->set('somedata.a.a', 1);
$this->get('session')->set('somedata.a.b', 2);
$this->get('session')->set('somedata.a.c', 3);
```

and get all the child sessions as an array from **'somedata.a'.**

```
$this->get('session')->get('somedata.a');
```

---

Currently using Symfony 3

Comment: You need to clarify what you are talking about.  These are strings?

Comment: have you tried `{% set somedataA = somedata.a %}` then use that variable instead?

Comment: It's a controller, I tried in the view just incase but doesn't work. I guess I have to write a preg_match loop to to get all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject this protected method to your controller and use it as helper:

```
protected function getSessionValuesByPrefix( $prefix )
{
    $result  = array();
    $session = $this->get('session');

    foreach ($session->all() as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, $prefix) === 0) {
            // We found a result ex: "someData.foo.bar", now lets explode
            $foundedSessionKeyToArray = explode('.', $key);
            // Now get the last part of the key
            $lastPart = end($foundedSessionKeyToArray);

            $result[$lastPart] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

So now you can get result by just calling:

```
$data = $this->getSessionValuesByPrefix('someData.a');
```